# Anchor | Fetching PDA results in: RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length

Tags: anchor, program, fetch

I am trying to fetch a specific PDA account using this method:

```
console.log(await this.program.account.item.fetch(itemPDA));
```

and it keeps resulting in an error for some reason:

```
RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length
```

I have trouble shooted and I know the PDA account has information in it. We recently switched IDL's and it worked on the last one. On this new one though it SHOULD work but it isn't. I asked our sc dev about it and he said it should be working and I am pretty sure he tested it out on his side and it worked. Here is the IDL:

```
{
  "name": "Item",
  "type": {
    "kind": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "price",
        "type": "u64"
      },
      {
        "name": "merchant",
        "type": "publicKey"
      },
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "mint",
        "type": "publicKey"
      },
      {
        "name": "thumbsUp",
        "type": "u64"
      },
      {
        "name": "thumbsDown",
        "type": "u64"
      },
      {
        "name": "itemsInStock",
        "type": "u64"
      },
      {
        "name": "cid",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you verify that you use the latest IDL after you upgraded your program maybe?

Comment: @vicyyn yeah, it is the latest since some functions don't work without it